# Can't install Drush 8

Tags: composer

I am following the instructions at https://docs.drush.org/en/7.x/install/

My PHP version is PHP 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.1.

When I run this command...

```
composer global require drush/drush:dev-master
```

...I get this output...

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for drush/drush dev-master -> satisfiable by drush/drush[dev-master].
    - drush/drush dev-master requires consolidation/site-process ^2.0.0-beta3 -> satisfiable by consolidation/site-process[2.0.0-beta3] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

However, I have minimum stability set to dev...

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
```

So why is the output telling me that beta code doesn't meet the "dev" stability level?

Comment: Where do you have minimum stability set? In the global composer.json?

Comment: Where is the global composer.json?

Comment: Usually in ~/.composer/

Comment: There is no such directory, though I have followed the instructions for installing composer globally at https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally

Comment: You’ll probably have to consult the composer docs for that, I know that every time I’ve installed it on a *nix based machine and been looking for it, it’s been where I mentioned. You can always just try creating a basic composer.json there with your stability settings in it

Comment: Alas, I am following the composer docs at https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#globally

Comment: Yeah that’s a pain, unfortunately Drupal can’t help you with that bit, Composer is its own ecosystem with its own rules

Comment: @arnoldbird, your instructions are outdated, don't try to install Drush 8 with `composer global require`, see http://docs.drush.org/en/8.x/install/.

Comment: @4k4 -- Thanks.  I followed those instructions and now get the proper drush help output when I run drush -v.  However, if I run drush cc, I am presented only with the option to clear the drush cache, and not my site's cache.  The only optiosn are 0 for "Cancel", and 1 for "drush".  How do I clear my site's cache?

Comment: `cd /var/www/directory_of_my_drupal_site`

Comment: Thanks!  That works now, if I supply the full path to /usr/local/bin/drush in my command.